# RTSP stream for QuickTime player does not show movie

Tags: javascript, rtsp, quicktime, movie

Did anybody faced to problem when QuickTime cannot play streaming video and shows blue question mark instead or errors - 400 (Bad Request) and 10060 (Disconnected)? I have already tried to switch getting stream from UFP to HTTP protocol with custom port in QuickTime settings but this did not help.

And does anybody know where can i find streaming video using RTSP protocol just for testing, links to online streams (not downloaded trailers) are appreciating.

These links do not work for me due to issue mentioned above:

http://mac.sillydog.org/qt/mov/embed_stream.php

And here only last one works (among other streaming types) :

http://quicktime.tc.columbia.edu/users/iml/movies/mtest.html

Thanks, for any links and advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that this was just a security issue and stream was stopped by private policy of Quick Time so to turn on the ability to play RTSP stream in Safari i needed to check some option in browser settings ...

http://www.niehs.nih.gov/news/video/help/

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to get rtsp streams to play in a browser window is using Apple's own  javascript.  I've tried hard coding  tags with exactly the same parameters, and the embed tags won't work, but the js will.  The js file itself is called AC_Quicktime.js.  Just google it and you should be able to find a link to it easily enough.  Use the one from Apple's site to make sure that you're getting unmodified code.  Load that in your HTML page, and in your body, insert this:

```
<script>
    QT_WriteOBJECT(*url*,*width*,*height*,*ActiveX Version*,*parameter1*,*value1*,*parameter2*,*value2*,*parameter3*,*value3*);
</script>
```

This will draw the appropriate code in whatever container you place the script.  ActiveX Version can be an empty string (''), and as many parameters as you like can be entered one after the other.  Apple has fairly exhaustive documentation on their website for all their stuff.[Apple Developer Connection](http://developer.apple.com).

Hope that was marginally helpful.